# Is there a way to programmatically update an app from the AppStore?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, app-store

I am developing my own app using Objective-C and C++. I want my app to be able to download the updates for other apps downloaded from the AppStore.
Does someone know if this is possible?

I know how to find which apps have a newer version via the iTunes search API.

Comment: You can just send user to updating page! You can NOT automatically update anything from appStore! Even the current app.

Comment: Have you tried the app called CleanMyMacX. It updates it somehow. How does that happen?

Comment: That is not on the APPSTORE. You can update from outside but again: NOT from the app store

Comment: Easy with the caps please. I am just asking. What is not on the app store?

Comment: I am making the app for myself I will not upload it to the AppStore. I just want to be able to view all the apps that are not up to date from the app store ( no third party apps ) and to be able to update them.

Comment: Sorry I’m on phone. Formatting is not easy when autocorrect presents ‍♂️. I just try to highlight important parts of the comment. You can’t update from the appstore without user action. But you can upload your package somewhere else, the you can do anything you want like updating (from your own site)

Comment: I got you. I am aware about the phones :D Thank you for the quick response